# Save file without Save Dialog in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6, autosave

I want to save a file without showing the save dialog because the file is always the same. How can I make it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The save dialog doesn't save a file, it simply presents the user with a method of selecting the file name and location for the file to be created.

If you want to save the file without displaying the save dialog, then don't display the save dialog.